# Removing duplicate items from ListBox in Delphi

Tags: delphi, for-loop, duplicates

How can I remove duplicate items from ListBox in Delphi? I know this:

```
for i := ListBox1.Items.Count-1 downto 1 do
     for j := 0 to i-1 do
       if ListBox1.Items[i] = ListBox1.Items[j] then
         ListBox1.Items.Delete[i];
```

But I need to remove duplicates only if first 10 letters are the same, so I have tried this:

```
for i := ListBox1.Items.Count-1 downto 1 do
         for j := 0 to i-1 do
           if copy(ListBox1.Items[i],1,11) = copy(ListBox1.Items[j],1,11) then
             ListBox1.Items.Delete[i];
```

But when I try to remove duplicates, I get list out of bonds error :(

Comment: Do you know what happens when you delete more than 1 item in first run when i=Count-1?

Comment: when you delete items, iterate the list **backwards**.

Comment: @Premature: He is.

Comment: If you know that your list is sorted, you can get away with comparing to the previous item. If you have to compare against EVERY prior item, then you're going to be exponentially slow, as your list grows.

Comment: @Andreas: Not on the inner loop he's not.

Comment: @afrazier : Andreas is correct, the deletion is made on items with index i.

Comment: Doesn't your code compare the first 11 letters?  Or, maybe I'm just fried at the end of the week?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a `break` after the `Delete`:

```
if Copy(ListBox1.Items[i], 1, 10) = Copy(ListBox1.Items[j], 1, 10) then
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Delete(i); 
  break;
end;
```

(Indeed, if you `Delete` the item with index `i`, then how can you make the comparison `if Copy(ListBox1.Items[i], 1, 10) = ...` the next time?)

Comment: @afrazier: My code above will work in any case. If some item occurs three times, or even 57 times, it will still work.

Comment: Doh!  You're right.  Oh, look, it's 5:00 on Friday (EDT)!  :-)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: the question states that he wants to compare the first 10 characters.  Doesn't your code compare eleven?  I realize that you just worked from his code, but there's no sense repeating the error.

Comment: @Argalatyr: OK, I have changed.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind sorting the items in `ListBox1` you can delete the duplicates in one pass.

```
var
  s: string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  ListBox1.Sorted := True;
  s := '';
  I := 0;
  while I < ListBox1.Count do
  begin
    if s = copy(ListBox1.Items[I], 1, 10) then
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.Delete(I);
    end
    else
    begin
      s := copy(ListBox1.Items[I], 1, 10);
      Inc(I);
    end;
  end;
end;
```